# How do i create edit control in win32 and c++ using object oriented techniques

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to create an edit control using oop techniques but i do not really understand what i am doing wrong. If someone can point out how I should go about doing this that will be very helpful. I have tried googling it but there is not alot out there because people do not code in win32 using Microsoft API i would try mfc but i am sticking with the win32 api.

```
#include <windows.h>

class winMaker
{
   public:
   winMaker(char * className,HINSTANCE hInstance);
   HWND create(const char * title);
   protected:
    HINSTANCE   _hInst;          
    char const *_className;      
    DWORD       _style;          
    DWORD       _exStyle;        
    char const *_title;          
    int         _x;              
    int         _y;              
    int         _width;          
    int         _height;         
    HWND        _hWndParent;     
    HMENU       _hMenu;           
    void *      _data;           
 };

 winMaker::winMaker(char * className,HINSTANCE hInstance) : 
  _style (WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW),
 _exStyle (0),
 _className (className),
_x (CW_USEDEFAULT),  
_y (0),              
_width (CW_USEDEFAULT),  
_height (0),         
_hWndParent (0),     
_hMenu (0),          
_data (0),           
_hInst (hInstance)
{
}

HWND winMaker::create(const char * title)  
{
 HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    _exStyle,
    _className,
    title,
    _style,
    _x,
    _y,
    _width,
    _height,
    _hWndParent,
    _hMenu,
    _hInst,
    NULL  
    );

    return hwnd;
  }

  class childMaker : public winMaker
  {
  public:
    childMaker(char * className,winApp appInstance, int childId);
    HWND create(const char * text = "");
 };

 childMaker::childMaker(char * className, winApp appInstance, int childId): 
 winMaker(className,appInstance.getInstance())
 {
    _style = WS_CHILD;
    _hWndParent = appInstance;
   _hMenu = reinterpret_cast<HMENU> (childId);
 }

 HWND childMaker::create(const char * text)
 {
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    _exStyle,
    _className,
    text,
    _style,
    _x,
    _y,
    _width,
    _height,
    _hWndParent,
    _hMenu,
    _hInst,
    0 //controller parameter goes here 
    );
   return hwnd;
 }
```

the code below is the window entry point where i make the call to my edit control class

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "winApp.h"
#include "winMaker.h"


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg,
              WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
           LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
MSG        Msg;
HWND       hWnd;
HWND       hnd;

winApp myWindow(hInstance,"window1","simp");
char * ClsName = myWindow.RegisterWindowStructure();

winMaker myWindowMaker(ClsName,hInstance);
hWnd = myWindowMaker.create("Simple Window");

myWindow.saveHwnd(hWnd);

childMaker editControl("EDIT",myWindow,0);
hnd = editControl.create();

// Find out if the window was created
if( !hWnd ) // If the window was not created,
    return 0; // stop the application

// Display the window to the user
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

// Decode and treat the messages
// as long as the application is running
while( GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) )
{
         TranslateMessage(&Msg);
         DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}

return Msg.wParam;
}
```

the code below is winMan class which contain methods for creating window class structure

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "windows.h"

class winApp
{
public:
    friend LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg,
                         WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

    winApp(HINSTANCE hInst,char nameOfStructWindow[],char MenuName[]);
    char * RegisterWindowStructure();
    HINSTANCE getInstance() const { return _hInstance; }
    operator HWND () const { return _h; }
    void saveHwnd(HWND h){ _h = h; }
    HWND returnHandle() { return _h; }
private:
    char * ClsName;
    char * menuName;
    HINSTANCE _hInstance;
    WNDCLASSEX _WndClsEx;
    HWND _h;
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg,
           WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Msg)
    {
     // If the user wants to close the application
    case WM_DESTROY:
    // then close it
    PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT);
    break;
   default:
    // Process the left-over messages
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
  }
  // If something was not done, let it go
  return 0;
}


winApp::winApp(HINSTANCE hInst,char nameOfStructWindow[],char MenuName[])
: ClsName(nameOfStructWindow),menuName(MenuName),_hInstance(hInst)
{
_WndClsEx.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    _WndClsEx.style         = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS;
    _WndClsEx.lpfnWndProc   = WndProcedure;
    _WndClsEx.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    _WndClsEx.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    _WndClsEx.hInstance     = hInst;
    _WndClsEx.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    _WndClsEx.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    _WndClsEx.hbrBackground = static_cast<HBRUSH>
                              (GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH));
    _WndClsEx.lpszMenuName  = MenuName;
    _WndClsEx.lpszClassName = ClsName;
    _WndClsEx.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
}

char * winApp::RegisterWindowStructure()
{
    RegisterClassEx(&_WndClsEx);
    return  ClsName;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What problem are you having?

Comment: i cannot see the edit control when i run the program im wondering am i doing it right

Comment: You are basically reinventing [MFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library) or [WTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Template_Library) and that would be a lot of work.

Comment: i like working with win32 api its cool

Comment: If the window is not visible then either the creation failed, the styles are wrong, it is not attached to the parent correctly, or the parent itself is not visible.   If you debug your code properly you will find which one(s) are the problem.  "The solution is left to the student."

Comment: i dont quite understand visual studio debug

Comment: You need to learn to use the debugger.  Debugging code is a crucial part of becoming a software developer.  Google for tutorials, read them or watch youtube videos.

Comment: ok i found the problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

The edit box got created with the default styles which is zero in this case 0 as it is not loaded from the resource in which the default style is specified.

So the size should be specified manually to make the edit box visible.

```
::SetWindowPos (hnd, HWND_TOP,0,0,100,100, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

I have used 100 for representational purpose.

You can also use other Win32 libraries available for window management. Reinventing is not a better option.